# расположение переменных внутри класса python

Tags: python, классы

Всем доброго времени суток, я новичок в ООП, пытаюсь сейчас написать текстового тамагочи. У меня есть вот такой код

```py
class Animal():
    def __init__(self, health, condition, food_size, time):
        self.health = float(health)
        self.food_size = float(food_size)
        self.condition = int(condition)
        self.time = int(time)
        
    def feed(self): 
        self.food += 20
```

Как и где будет более правильно прописать изначальное состояние переменных `food`, `health`, `food_size`? Помогите пожалуйста. Всем заранее спасибо большое, и доброго вечера!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При инициализации объекта, в методе `__init__()`

```py
class Animal():
    def __init__(self, health=100, condition=1, food_size=20, time=2):
        self.health = float(health)
        self.food_size = float(food_size)
        self.condition = int(condition)
        self.time = int(time)
        
    def feed(self): 
        self.food += 20
```

Указать значения по умолчанию, как в коде выше. При отклонении от дефолтной логики, по именнованным параметрам указывать необходимые значения.

То есть

```py
# default
pet_default = Animal()

# другие параметры на старте
pet_fat = Animal(health=1000)
```

Comment: def __init__(self, health = 100, condition = "Perfecto!", food_size = 20, time):
так к примеру?

Comment: @PavelOrlov ну да

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду знать!